# Simplest way to exclude a large list (500) of strings in SQL?

Tags: sql

I need to minimize the manual work required with large list to not manually enter all of them.

Would the best approach be to just search replace , with | and do this?

WHERE email NOT REGEXP 'abcd|fsdfds|dsfds|dfsdf|dsfdsf'

Comment: Exclude them from what? Post some more details, show what you have, in your CSV, and th query youre trying to run and what bearing the contents of the CSV have on the query

Comment: What database? Can you create a table out of those names, or are you restricted from making changes to the database?

Comment: What exactly is the format you have?

Answer (score 0):

Load the CSV file into a table, say `strings` and run something like:

```
select t.*
from t
where not exists (select 1 from strings where t.col = strings.string);
```

You can declare the column in `strings` to be a primary key to improve performance.